# How to communicate with pic micro controller using Android device via UART pin?

Tags: android, android-kernel

I have a ODROID C2 with Android 5.1. It has an UART pin.
I want to communicate with pic micro controller using UART serial communication.

I tried [this](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html). i can see uart port on device manager.but the problem is i cant install app on the device.  it shows error: 
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.windows10.uart_app
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.windows10.uart_app
Unknown failure (Failure)

Answer (score 0):

First, u need to check the voltage level of PIC UART. Maybe it is 5V.

And, ODROID C2 uses 3V3 UART level. (Must use UART1 from C2 GPIO. if u use UART0, u'll need some modifing at boot.ini)

Second, test with some serial APP. if the APP shows same error, u'll need to give permission as

> ## chmod 777 /dev/tty1

Also, why don't you use Hardkernel's forum?

---

EDIT
Sorry, #chmod 777 /dev/tty1 is wrong. retry #chmod 777 /dev/ttyS1

Comment: i had used a code from github. But i got the same error.  Error:: pkg: /data/local/tmp/uart_com
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.windows10.uart_com
Unknown failure (Failure)

Comment: Did you run test with terminal? if not, try it "echo "1" > /dev/ttyS1

Comment: Try after "sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyS1"